# Executing promises in sequence: understanding a claim made about this example code

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6

I'm not looking for a solution for how to execute promises in sequence, I'm trying to understand the one given by a blog author:

I am reading ["We have a problem with promises"](http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html) by Nolan Lawson, posted 18 May 2015.

Under "Advanced mistake #3: promises vs promise factories" he has this example that is supposed to be the working one:

```js
// Setup, just a meta explanation what a function looks like
function promiseFactory() {
  return somethingThatCreatesAPromise();
}

// Actual example; promiseFactories could be an Array
function executeSequentially(promiseFactories) {
    var result = Promise.resolve();
    promiseFactories.forEach(function (promiseFactory) {
        result = result.then(promiseFactory);
    });
    return result;
}
```

I don't understand why that works. `forEach` executes all functions at once. `result` will be a resolved promise so `promiseFactory` is run right away?

I don't get how this code is supposed to ensure the code in the `promiseFactory` functions runs in sequence.

Comment: Yes, the first `promiseFactory` is run right away. The others are not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `forEach` executes all functions at once

No, it runs them *one after another*. `forEach` is **not asynchronous**.

So let's look at an example iteration:

```
// The first result is already resolved, so as to allow
// the first 'then' to trigger
var result = Promise.resolve();
promiseFactories.forEach(function (promiseFactory) {
    // First iteration: result = ResolvedPromise.then(promiseFactory)
    // Second iteration result = promiseFactoryResult.then(nextPromiseFactory);
    // and so on...
    result = result.then(promiseFactory);
});
```

So it loops through the array-like object, one after another, chaining the result of promises created by the `nextPromiseFactory` onto the `result` variable.

It's essentially the same as doing:

```
var result = Promise.resolve().then(promiseFactory).then(promiseFactory).then(promiseFactory);
```